# C# for loop on button1_click1, int i seems to be advancing wrong

Tags: c#

Trying to get it so that if you left click, it will fill in 4 text boxes, then if you use the dropdownlists and click on it again, it will fill in 4 different text boxes - have to get it to fill a total of 20, 4 at a time.

```
    int carpick, qty, total, i;

    protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (i = 0; i != 5; ++i)
        {
            carpick = 0; qty = 0; total = 0;
            {

                carpick = Convert.ToInt32(CarpickDD.SelectedItem.Value);
                qty = Convert.ToInt32(QTYDD.SelectedItem.Value);
                total = ((carpick * qty) + (750 * qty));

                Label1.Text = CarpickDD.SelectedItem.Text;
                Label2.Text = CarpickDD.SelectedItem.Value;
                Label3.Text = QTYDD.SelectedItem.Value;
                Label4.Text = Convert.ToString(total);}

        if (i != 1)
        {

            carpick = Convert.ToInt32(CarpickDD.SelectedItem.Value);
            qty = Convert.ToInt32(QTYDD.SelectedItem.Value);
            total = ((carpick * qty) + (750 * qty));
            Label5.Text = CarpickDD.SelectedItem.Text;
            Label6.Text = CarpickDD.SelectedItem.Value;
            Label7.Text = QTYDD.SelectedItem.Value;
            Label8.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
       }

        }
    }
```

`enter code here`

Answer (score 2):

Every time you click on the button, your `for` loop starts at `i = 0`. Therefore, you are not maintaining any state from each invocation to the next; your button doesn’t “remember” how often you have clicked it before.

That said, you are also not making *any* use of the variable `i` inside the loop (except for the `if (i != 1)`). In other words, your loop currently does *the same thing on every button click*, and it does *the same thing five times for each click*. If you want to fill in *different* text boxes the second time you click on the button, surely it should do something different the second time round?

Comment: ok, I see what you're saying - but is there a way to get it to advance?  I'm really new to this, and don't know much

Answer (score 0):

I think you want this:

```
int carpick, qty, total, i = 0;

protected void Button1_Click1(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    carpick = Convert.ToInt32(CarpickDD.SelectedItem.Value);
    qty = Convert.ToInt32(QTYDD.SelectedItem.Value);
    total = ((carpick * qty) + (750 * qty));

    switch (i++)
    {
        case 0:
            Label1.Text = CarpickDD.SelectedItem.Text;
            Label2.Text = CarpickDD.SelectedItem.Value;
            Label3.Text = QTYDD.SelectedItem.Value;
            Label4.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
            break;

        case 1:
            Label5.Text = CarpickDD.SelectedItem.Text;
            Label6.Text = CarpickDD.SelectedItem.Value;
            Label7.Text = QTYDD.SelectedItem.Value;
            Label8.Text = Convert.ToString(total);
            break;

        case 2:
            ..... etc ....
    }
}
```

Comment: This is close to what I want - the only thing I don't get when I debug it is that I want it to end up with more than one line - it looks like when I click the button, it just reloads the page and doesn't keep the previous labels